# Unwrapping variadic template structs

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I'm trying to create an `variant` struct, i.e. a struct that contains one of so many types. Here is my attempt so far:

```
template <typename Type, typename... Rest> struct OneOf {
    union {
        Type value;
        OneOf<Rest...> rest;
    };
};

template <typename Type> struct OneOf {
    Type value;
};
```

Sadly, this doesn't compile. When I try to instantiate it, I get:

> one_of.h:34:33: error: redeclared with 1 template parameter  template
>    struct OneOf {

Is there a way to terminate a self referencing recursion with structs?

Comment: FWIW, you are trying to make a variant.  A variant can be one of a set of types.  An any type is limitless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first declare the *primary template*, and then declare any *specializations* (either full or partial). The primary template determines the number and kind of template arguments. When it comes time to instantiate the template, a full specialization will be used if it matches exactly, or the best-matching partial specialization if any match, otherwise, the primary template will be instantiated.

If you want `OneOf` to be a template that takes any number of type template arguments (0 or more), then you should declare the primary template accordingly:

```
template <class... T> struct OneOf;
```

Then you'll need two specializations: one for the base case of the recursion, which can be taken to be the empty pack:

```
template <>
struct OneOf<> {};
```

and one for the recursive case, with at least one template parameter:

```
template <typename Type, typename... Rest> struct OneOf<Type, Rest...> {
    union {
        Type value;
        OneOf<Rest...> rest;
    };
};
```

Notice that both full and partial specializations require a template argument list after the template name. If you omit this, the compiler will think you are redeclaring the primary template, which causes the error you're seeing.

Comment: I'm actually quite fine with the form I wrote (where zero types are not acceptable). Otherwise, this is definitely the most complete answer.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh Fair enough---then you can declare the primary template so that it takes 1 type or more, the base case to take exactly 1 type, and the recursive case to take 2 or more types. It's a little more verbose that way.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to write a specialization.

This is the syntax:

```
template <typename Type> struct OneOf<Type> {
//                                   ^~~~~~
    Type value;
};
```

Comment: It works, but I don't understand it. Can you elaborate on why the `<Type>` is needed, and why it isn't needed for the first form?

Comment: Just search for template specialization. Here are some starting points: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
template <typename...>
struct OneOf;

template <typename Type, typename... Rest>
struct OneOf<Type, Rest...> {
    union {
        Type value;
        OneOf<Rest...> rest;
    };
};

template <>
struct OneOf<> {
};
```

?

O also

```
template <typename, typename...>
struct OneOf;

template <typename T0, typename T1, typename ... Ts>
struct OneOf<T0, T1, Ts...> {
    union {
        T0 value;
        OneOf<T1, Rest...> rest;
    };
};

template <typename T0>
struct OneOf<T0> {
    T0 value;
};
```

?